# When should I overload new/delete in C++

Tags: c++

I have learned something about overloading new/delete in 《C++ Primer》.But I am very curious :as the default new/delete is so good,When should I overload them?

Comment: I sometime used to overload them to add tracing to memory allocation, so I could know when and where a block of memory were allocated, as a sort of debugging help.

Comment: First rule of optimization: *Measure, optimize, measure.* On-topic corrolary: Only overload new / delete when you have *proof* that it is indeed necessary. *Then* prove that you didn't make thinks worse. ;)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Strictly speaking, that's not overloading, but replacement.  (It may be the sort of thing the OP had in mind, however.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only overload them when you've got specific memory requirements for your class. For example, if you want to ensure that all instances of `Foo` are allocated out of a memory pool.

Other than this sort of thing it's rare to need to overload them.

Answer (score 2):

At the class level, the usual reason for overloading them is to use a
memory pool.  This is typically only useful for very small classes which
will be dynamically allocated a lot; things like nodes in a graph, for
example, where a pool allocator may significantly improve locality and
allocation/deallocation speed.

You can also overload the global new and delete operators to use special
allocators (say allocating from a specific area in memory).  This can be
tricky, however, since there is no way to specify the additional
arguments in a delete expression.  Practically speaking, when you do
this, you also have to replace the non-placement new and delete
operators, and arrange for the new operators to somehow store the
information necessary to find the correct deleter.

And of course, although not overloading, you can replace the global new
and delete operators, with ones that are instrumented to collect
information concerning allocations and deletions, for debugging
purposes (or because you have some custom placement new/delete).

You should *not* do anything with the global new/delete in a library.
Since anything you do will require replacing the non-placement forms,
doing it in a library will risk conflicts (if the user also needs to do
it in his main application).

Answer (score 1):

Also If you create a custom allocation library like [TCMalloc](http://code.google.com/p/gperftools/?redir=1) and you want that all allocations from `new` in a program go to your library.

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting document on [Facebook's FBVector](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/FBVector.md) type in their folly library, which explains why they use a custom allocator for vectors, in particular it permits in-place reallocation, optimised growth factor to avoid gcc's allocation crawl, and so on.

Generally, it's a bad idea to do allocation yourself, because it's a complex issue with a lot of trade-off decisions to make.

Answer (score 1):

Some use cases that come to mind:

- Tracing memory allocations and deallocations, as @Joachim Pileborg said. Tools such as valgrind or address sanitizer can do that for you, but doing it yourself allow to target only a subset of allocations and thus have less impact on performances
- Using a custom allocation mechanism, for instance producing aligned addresses (for SSE, or other hardware requirements), or allocating in shared memory, or using a memory pool, or allocating at specific address for low level driver needs
- Use a different allocation algorithm than the one supplied with your compiler/standard library. Depending on your allocations and threading patterns, selecting an appropriate allocation policy may improve performance.